# Error installing faiss-cpu with pip: swig.exe command failed during wheel build for Python 3.12.0

Tags: python-3.x, windows, swig, python-3.12

I'm trying to install the `faiss-cpu` package in my Python environment, but I'm encountering a build error related to `swig.exe` during the wheel building process. I'm working within a virtual environment on Windows and using Python 3.12.0.

Here's the error message I receive when I run `pip install faiss-cpu`:

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for faiss-cpu (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [details of the error]
swig.exe -python -c++ -Doverride= -I/usr/local/include -Ifaiss -doxygen -DSWIGWIN -module swigfaiss -o faiss\faiss\python\swigfaiss_wrap.cpp faiss\faiss\python\swigfaiss.i
error: command 'swig.exe' failed: None
```

[image]

**Note: I have noticed a notification about a newer version of pip being available. Not sure if that's part of the issue.**

To troubleshoot, I've attempted the following:

1. Ensured that `swig` is installed and the path to `swig.exe` is in my system's PATH environment variable. Running `swig -version` in the command prompt returns the version correctly.
2. I haven't yet updated pip and setuptools to the latest versions, but I noticed the notification about the new pip version (23.3.2).
3. I have not checked if Visual C++ Build Tools are required and properly installed for this package.

I expected the package to install without any issues as I followed the standard pip installation procedure. I'm wondering if the issue is specific to my Python version (3.12.0) or some other configuration on my system.

Comment: unpack the pip package, extract the needed files and run the swig command yourself - you will probably get a more verbose error message

Answer (score 0):

In the current latest faiss-cpu package, 1.7.4, they specify up to python 3.11 -- it worked for me when downgraded to that version.
https://pypi.org/project/faiss-cpu/1.7.4/